# javascript not properly running on my website on IE browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

I created a website and it works perfectly fine on chrome but on IE the js doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure what's going on because I added a < noscript > tag to check if JS wasn't loading but it doesn't show up (which means JS is running fine), and I went to some of those "check if JS is enabled on your browser" sites and they all said it was working.

Then I checked the settings and it had it enabled as well. So JavaScript seems to be working but the JS on my website (such as smoothly scrolling down when I click a link in the navbar) isn't working.

Anyone have any reasons as to why? Am I forgetting to put an extra tag or something. Any help is appreciated

Comment: any output on the developer console?

Comment: IE is dreaded on the internet. It lags behind when it comes to implementing new JavaScript features and it can be a bit hard to know what new features one might have used. You can open developer tools in IE to check for errors or use [caniuse](https://caniuse.com) to search for specific features

Comment: Please post code sample or screenshot of issue.

Comment: It's impossible for us to know what specifically is causing the incompatibility, since you haven't posted any code.

Comment: I checked under console, but it's perfectly empty. No errors.

Comment: What would you like to see? I'm not sure what type of code you'd like since it's not like the website isn't working - it's just that isn't working on IE.

Comment: Please describe this in more detail: "*the js doesn't seem to be working*"

Comment: Put `console.log("The JS is running");` at the beginning of your JS, do you see that log message?

Comment: Yes I can, but now I also see an error saying "Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'" and I went to where it's referencing and it's just "document.querySelectorAll('.itemSelect').forEach(function(e){ ... }" and I checked caniuse and querySelectorAll seems ok to use. (This error doesn't come up on chrome)

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelectorAll returns a NodeList NOT an array. forEach on a NodeList is not supported in IE. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Browser_compatibility

It should work if you replace the forEach with a For loop or use the Array.prototype.forEach (which is also documented on the page in the link above)